# I am having issues deploying my VBA VSTO. I am using the Setup extension with Microsoft Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, vsto, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create an installer for an outlook add-in built in VS 2019 Community.  I am using the setup extension.  It works on my local computer but only because it is the device the VSTO was created on. My problem is create it work universally. When I check the add-in location that works locally, it is pointing to the VSTO in my visual studio project.

I have added the primary project output to the Application Folder in the File System setting, and I have changed the Register property to vsdrpCOM.

It works locally like I mentioned, but I need it to work universally. It does produce a setup.exe and setup.msi as well. I know it is something little I am missing but I thought I would turn to the community for some help.

Comment: Do you see the add-in listed in the COM add-ins list on the target machine?

Comment: No, on my local machine(the machine that created the project) I do.  Outlook says the add-in location is: "project directory/bin/release/filename.vsto|vstolocal"

Comment: Looks like the add-in was not registered correctly on the target machine. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019 .

Comment: The article doesn't work for me because I am using the setup extension, not installshield.  I am using VS community, which installshield does not support.

Comment: The steps are common for all kind of Windows Installer projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you included all the required prerequisites to the add-in installer. This is the first point to check among others.

Make sure that you did steps described in the [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I forgot to update the answer.

My issue pertained to creating the registry keys. I thought the keys would populate in the setup project, I was not aware I had to create every key myself. This was my first time doing a project like this.

So the short answer is make sure you create all the keys as posted in the link above by Eugene.